# 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004.'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, data-structures

I created this linked list class to use it in my work but I have this exception 'First-chance exception at 0x003216D2 in game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004.' and it is coming from erase function can someone show me how can fix it and explain what it the problem

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_HPP
#define LINKEDLIST_HPP


#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

template<typename T>
class Linkedlist
{
private:    
    // The basic doubly linked Linkedlist node.
    // Nested inside of Linkedlist, can be public
    // because the Node is itself private
    struct Node
    {
        T  _data;
        Node   *_prev;
        Node   *_next;

        Node( const T & d = T(), Node * p = NULL, Node * n = NULL )
            : _data( d ), _prev( p ), _next( n ) { }


        // Rvalue   
        Node(Node && n)
        {
            _data = std::move(n._data);
            _prev = std::move(n._prev);
            _next = std::move(n._next);
        }

        // = operator
        Node& operator =(Node && n)
        {
            _data = std::move(n._data);
            _prev = std::move(n._prev);
            _next = std::move(n._next);
            return *this;
        }
    };
public:
    class LinkedListIter : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag , T , int>
    {
        Node* _node;
    public:
        LinkedListIter(Node* p=nullptr) : _node(p){}
        ~LinkedListIter(){}

        Node* getNode(){return _node;}

        T operator * () { return _node->_data; }
        LinkedListIter & operator ++()
        {
            _node = _node->_next;
            return *this; 
        }

        LinkedListIter operator ++(int)
        {
            LinkedListIter  retVal = *this;
            ++this;
            return retVal;
        }
        bool operator < (LinkedListIter const& rhs) const
        { 
            return _Node < rhs._Node; 
        }
        bool operator != (LinkedListIter const& rhs) const
        {
            return _Node != rhs._pNode;
        }
        bool operator == (LinkedListIter const& rhs) const 
        {
            return _Node == rhs._Node;
        }
    };



    Linkedlist( )
    { init(); }

    ~Linkedlist()
    {
        clear();
        delete _head;
        delete _tail;
    }

    Linkedlist(const Linkedlist & rhs)
    {
        init( );
        *this = rhs;
    }

    const Linkedlist & operator= (const Linkedlist & rhs)
    {
        if( this == &rhs )
            return *this;
        clear( );
        for(const_iterator itr = rhs.begin(); itr != rhs.end( ); ++itr)
            push_back(*itr);
        return *this;
    }

    // Return iterator representing beginning of Linkedlist.
    // Mutator version is first, then accessor version.
    LinkedListIter begin()
    { return LinkedListIter(_head->_next);}


    // Return iterator representing endmarker of Linkedlist.
    // Mutator version is first, then accessor version.
    LinkedListIter end()
    { return LinkedListIter(_tail); }


    // Return number of elements currently in the Linkedlist.
    int size() const
    { return _size; }

    // Return true if the Linkedlist is empty, false otherwise.
    bool empty() const
    { return size() == 0; }

    void clear()
    {
        while( !empty() )
            pop_front();
    }

    // front, back, push_front, push_back, pop_front, and pop_back
    // are the basic double-ended queue operations.
    T & front()
    //{ return *begin( ); }
    {return _head->_next.data}
    const T & front() const
    { return *begin(); }

    T & back( )
    { return *--end(); }

    const T & back() const
    { return *--end(); }

    void push_front(const T & x)
    { insert( begin(), x ); }

    void push_back(const T & x)
    { insert( end(), x ); }

    void pop_front()
    { erase(begin()); }

    void pop_back()
    { erase(--end()); }

    // Insert x before itr.
    LinkedListIter insert(LinkedListIter& itr, const T & x)
    {
        Node *p = new Node(x,itr.getNode()->_prev,itr.getNode());
        _size++;
        return LinkedListIter(p->_prev = p->_prev->_next = new Node(x, p->_prev, p));
    }

    // Erase item at itr.
    LinkedListIter  erase(LinkedListIter itr)
    {
        Node *p = itr.getNode();
        LinkedListIter retVal(p->_next);
        p->_prev->_next = p->_next;
        p->_next->_prev = p->_prev;
        delete p;
        _size--;

        return retVal;


    }

    LinkedListIter erase(LinkedListIter start, LinkedListIter end)
    {
        for(iterator itr = start; itr != end;)
            itr = erase(itr);

        return end;
    }

private:
    int   _size;
    Node *_head;
    Node *_tail;




    void init()
    {
        _size = 0;
        _head = new Node;
        _tail = new Node;
        _head->_next = _tail;
        _tail->_prev = _head;
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Unless you're doing homework that requires writing your own class, use std::list. It works! Why are you using rvalue references (&&)? I'm guessing you are learning C++, and I'm guessing you don't get the nuances of rvalues. Hint: the compiler will write those default rvalue functions for you if you play your cards right.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see what line the error is on?

Comment: Write unit tests that verify that it works as expected. Start off with completely simple cases for things that are really simple, like, `size()` returns zero when first constructed, `size()` returns one after pushing one item, after pushing one item, `front()` returns that item properly, etc. It is far easier to investigate an issue in a tiny test case that does a few things than it is to dig through some big complex crash when using it for real tasks. As more and more tests pass, add new tests that are more and more brutal.

Comment: @jeffamaphone the exception happen in line erase function the line p->_next->_prev = p->_prev;

Comment: @user3277743: so in `p->_next->_prev` the subexpression `p->_next` is null. You have a pretty good hint of what is wrong, the `_next` pointer of a node is null. Now check how that node was created and inserted and whether null is a valid value for that pointer.

Answer (score 5):

An access violation (in windows, or a segmentation fault in unices) indicates that you attempted to access memory incorrectly. Either you attempted to access memory outside of your process space, or you attempted the wrong type of access.

The error message is also telling you what the address that you attempted to access is and what type of access you attempted. You attempted a write to memory address 0x00000004, that is 4 bytes off from the zeroth address. That looks like you attempted to write through a null pointer and that the write is to a member 4 bytes off from the beginning of the object.

While it is not always possible to determine what the real cause is, this is what it *looks like*. The easiest way of debugging the problem is to run your application in a debugger and have the debugger tell you where the access violation is. Then inspect the state of the program and attempt to determine how it ended up in that situation.

Comment: the problem I can't debug the value of p->_prev->_next = p->_next;because is us pointer I tried to add watcher to see the values i can't

Comment: @user3277743: Let it crash inside the debugger, it will tell you which pointer was null. Then try to figure out how it came to that. If that does not help, then try to reduce the code to the minimal crashing piece and step inside the program. What function is crashing? How was the list initialized before? Can you check what is wrong before it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your pointers. Try to debug `erase` function carefully.

The `Access violation` error usually takes place when your pointers point to "foreign" memory region (i.e. memory which is not keeped by your application).

Answer (score 0):

You probably tried to erase the tail node.  The tail node's `next` pointer is NULL (from the default constructor).